# Why is this mock jest test failing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, navigator

I am trying to mock document.clipboard.

Here is my code:

```
  handleCopyIdToClipboard = () => {
    const el = document.querySelector(`.${CLASS_NAME}`);
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(el.textContent);

    // some extra code
    showPopup();
  };
```

Here is my jest test:

```
describe('handleCopyToClipboard', () => {
const mockQuerySelector = jest.fn();
const mockBoundingClientRect = jest.fn();
const mockClipboard = jest.fn();
const mockWriteText = jest.fn();

mockQuerySelector.mockReturnValue({textContent: 'someText', getBoundingClientRect: mockBoundingClientRect});
mockBoundingClientRect.mockReturnValue({top: 100, left: 100});

Object.defineProperty(document, 'querySelector', {value: mockQuerySelector});
Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'clipboard', {value: mockClipboard});
Object.defineProperty(navigator.clipboard, 'writeText', {value: mockWriteText});

beforeEach(() =>
  [mockQuerySelector, mockClipboard, mockWriteText, mockBoundingClientRect].map(mock =>
    mock.mockClear(),
  ),
);

it('should copy to clipboard', () => {
  const wrapper = buildComponent(DetailsPage, props);
  wrapper.instance().handleCopyIdToClipboard('id');

  expect(mockQuerySelector).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockClipboard).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockWriteText).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mockBoundingClientRect).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(wrapper.state().showPopup).toEqual(true);
  expect(wrapper.state().top).toEqual(90);
  expect(wrapper.state().left).toEqual(200);
});
```

});

This line fails `expect(mockClipboard).toHaveBeenCalled();` indicating that mockClipboard is never called. But if i remove this line, `expect(mockWriteText).toHaveBeenCalled();` does not fail. Any idea?

Edit:

I have updated my function to the following:

```
  handleCopyIdToClipboard = () => {
    navigator.clipboard
      .writeText(this.state.urn)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({showPopup: true});
      })
      .catch(doNothing);
  };
```

and current jest test:

```
  describe('handleCopyToClipboard', () => {
    const mockClipboard = jest.fn();
    const mockWriteText = jest.fn();

    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'clipboard', {value: mockClipboard});
    Object.defineProperty(navigator.clipboard, 'writeText', {value: mockWriteText});

    beforeEach(() => [mockClipboard, mockWriteText].map(mock => mock.mockClear()));

  it('should copy to clipboard', () => {
    const wrapper = buildComponent(ServiceAccountDetailsPage, props);

    mockWriteText.mockReturnValueOnce(true);

    return wrapper
        .instance()
        .handleCopyIdToClipboard()
        .then(() => {
          expect(mockWriteText).toHaveBeenCalled();
          expect(wrapper.state().showPopup).toEqual(true);
        });
  });
});
```

running into this error: `navigator.clipboard.writeText(...).then is not a function`. I would like to test both `.then()` and `.catch()` blocks

Answer (score 0):

[Navigator.clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard) is not a function, you shouldn't mock it as a function. You should mock the entire `clipboard` object. E.g.

`main.ts`:

```js
export function handleCopyIdToClipboard() {
  const el = document.querySelector('.class-name');
  const textContent = el ? el.textContent || '' : '';
  return navigator.clipboard.writeText(textContent);
}
```

`main.test.ts`:

```js
import { handleCopyIdToClipboard } from './main';

describe('61348091', () => {
  it('should pass', async () => {
    const mElement = { textContent: 'hello' };
    const mockQuerySelector = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mElement);
    const mockWriteText = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('clipText');
    Object.defineProperty(document, 'querySelector', { value: mockQuerySelector });
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'clipboard', {
      value: {
        writeText: mockWriteText,
      },
    });
    const actual = await handleCopyIdToClipboard();
    expect(actual).toBe('clipText');
    expect(mockQuerySelector).toBeCalledWith('.class-name');
    expect(mockWriteText).toBeCalledWith('hello');
  });
});
```

unit test results with coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61348091/main.test.ts (16.222s)
  61348091
    ✓ should pass (6ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 main.ts  |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 3                 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        18.23s
```

Comment: wow thanks so much for the help. I've updated my question based on some changes I've made. If you can take another look I would really appreciate it. In the meantime I will look at your example to see what I was doing wrong

Comment: @ronapple14 updated answer, please check. Use `mockResolvedValue` for `mockWriteText`

Comment: @slideshow2 handleCopyIdToClipboard() returns a Promise. By the way, is the return needed in order for testing? I can probably wrap it around Promise.Resolve() if it makes sense

Comment: No, you don't need to return. I just made a demonstration. You can wrap it around Promise.Resolve(), but make sure the promise is resolved or rejected in your test case. See: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous

Comment: hmm.. I'm still getting "navigator.clipboard.writeText(...).then is not a function"

Comment: @ronapple14 You should mock the entire `clipboard` object. Your updated code is still incorrect. Besides, you should use `mockResolvedValueOnce` **NOT** `mockReturnValueOnce `